# Using EventWaitHandle class

Tags: c#, ipc, event-wait-handle

in Process A I need to receive an event  from Proces B. I decided to use EventWaitHandle. 
In both processes i write this code:

```
var evhandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset,"MyGUID1221");
```

then in process A i invoke Set() method:

```
evhandle.Set();
```

How i can to receive "MyGUID1221" event in process B and do some actions?
 How to make "MyGUID1221"Listener?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "MyGUID121" is just the name for the system-wide event.
You *listen* (read wait) for the event by using the [WaitOne](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd.aspx) - method

Comment: i add evhandle.WaitOne();  method to process A, but how i can to run some function when MyGUID1221" event is invoked? I dont see some EventWaitHandle events, which rises when system invoke MyGUID1221 event

Comment: WaitOne will wait for the event to be set. You can check if the event is set by using WaitOne(0) (will return true if set and false if not) - there are no events as you usually know them but you can use a Task to await the handle and/or ContinueWith on this as some kind of event-handler